# Eclipse errors preventing me from building project

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu

I have this problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799281/type-internal-compiler-error-eclipse

I am wondering if it is related to my console also spitting out this error when i start a fresh install of Java-EE Eclipse (2019-03):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48467865/glib-critical-g-base64-encode-step-assertion-in-null-failed-problems-i

I tried to change the GTK environment variables but surprise surprise they don't exist.

I haven't done anything particular special on my installation except:

- start with Ubuntu then install the Kubuntu packages through apt
- install Latte Dock
- set GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx (otherwise I can't even install Eclipse)
- set theme to Breeze Dark and add icons (Zafiro-icons-black-red)

Running Eclipse 2019-03, OpenJDK 11/8 (tried both), Kubuntu 18.04.

EDIT: My org.eclipse.swt.internal settings:

```
org.eclipse.swt.internal.deviceZoom=100
org.eclipse.swt.internal.gdk.backend=x11
org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.theme=Breeze
org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.version=3.22.30
```

Comment: I'm trying to run Eclipse on Kubuntu with default packages and default dependencies and it isn't working. Not really sure what else you'd like me to specify.

Comment: so it never works are are there conditions under which you've gotten it to run?

Comment: The IDE does boot, it just refuses to compile anything because it's constantly firing off ClassPathExceptions

Comment: it really seems this has nothing to do with kubuntu at all.

Comment: I am under the impression that the error might have something to do with the GTK library (or some deficiency of it) in Kubuntu. In order to even get Eclipse to boot I had to set the GTK_IM_MODULE parameter. I can't be the only one trying to use Eclipse on Kubuntu...